# mount a NFS volume on a container

Tags: mount, docker, nfs, volume, nfsv4

I have a NFS server that export a file-system.

```
showmount -e nfsserver
Export list for nfsserver:
/opt/application/aghas0/docker client1,client2
```

on the client2 server I have mounted the file-system from the nfsserver and that worked.

```
nfsserver:/opt/application/aghas0/docker  9.8G   23M  9.2G   1% /opt/application/aghas0/docker
```

so I tried to create a NFS Docker Volume named nfsvol

```
docker volume inspect nfsvol
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-07-16T16:31:47+02:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nfsvol/_data",
        "Name": "nfsvol",
        "Options": {
            "device": ":/opt/application/aghas0/docker",
            "o": "addr=nfsserver_Ip,rw",
            "type": "nfs"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

but when I try to mount this volume to a container I get the error bellow:

```
docker run -it -v nfsvol:/mnt alpine sh
docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume with options: type='nfs' device=':/opt/application/aghas0/docker' o='addr=10.118.120.46,rw': input/output error.
```

I am using NFS4.
I don't know if there is a specific configuration for this version. Does any one know how to fix this please ?

Comment: I am getting confused as to what is what. Is it a client, is it a server?

Comment: Can you include `Dockerfile`

Comment: I created the docker volume on the client server and started a basic alpine image

Comment: client server = server that mount the filesystem shared by the nfs server.
nfsvol is a docker volume created on the client server

Comment: yep... that is just semantics, I don't believe that change the problem understanding. I have to rhel server that are client to my nfs server...

English isn't my first language so I try my best to be clear... sorry if it wasn't the case for you

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I had to pass as an option the nfs version used, when I create the docker volume,like this :

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=addr=nfsserver_IP,rw,vers=4 --opt device=:/opt/application/aghas0/ansible nfsvol
```

this has solved my problem